# display specific div on hover? using css and html only

Tags: html, css, hover

I want to show second `div` (in HTML) with class `dikh`a on cursor hover over anchor tag.

HTML CODE:

```
<a>Hover over me!</a>
<div class="faraz"> sdjfg </div>
<div class="dikha">Stuff shown on hover</div>
```

STYLE

```
div {
display: none;
}

a:hover > div:nth-child(2) {
display: block;
background-color: RED;
height: 250px;
width: 960px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the adjacent siblings selector `~`.  Also, the div you want to show is the third child, not the second (because the `<a>` is the first).

```
div {
    display: none;
}
a:hover ~ div:nth-child(3) {
    display: block;
    background-color: RED;
    height: 250px;
    width: 960px;
}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3eFhf/**

Comment: Thanks it worked. another problem i was having is with DREAMWEAVER it wasnt showing exact results. thanks

Answer (score 6):

Write like this:

```
a:hover ~ .dikha {
    display: block;
    background-color: RED;
    height: 250px;
    width: 960px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use javascript function here.

> < onmouseover="document.getElementById('myid').style.display='block'">
>
> < id="myid" class="dikha">

Your dikha class should be hidden by default

> .dikha { display:none; }

you can also use jquery slidetoggle method to achieve this

Comment: question stands for "using css and html only"

Comment: sorry i mentioned in question heading that i only require it to be done using css n html.. thanks