# hovering over a tag, but not showing the menu

Tags: html, css

im trying to make a very simple menu here
basically i want to hover over the link and a menu show up.
but its not showing up!
i nested 2 tags inside of each other and gave em ids.
u can see the rest in code.

```css
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: no-display;
}

#headermenu {
  display: none;
}

#amenu:hover #headermenu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul id="Header">
    <li>
      <a id="amenu">aaaa
        <div id="headermenu">
          <ul>
            <li><a>menue yek</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: use dev tools to see that you have issue with your code

Comment: refer link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15543159/display-specific-div-on-hover-using-css-and-html-only

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using only CSS, show div on hover over <a>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210033/using-only-css-show-div-on-hover-over-a)

Comment: u r about to highlight a link on hover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your rendered html.

#### The Issue:

The behaviour you are observing is a result of the html not being processed in the manner in which you are expecting.

*Most likely because you are trying to open another anchor link within an existing one*, e.g: `<a href="#">containing link <a href="#">nested link</a></a>`

**What's occurring in your use-case is most likely what's occurring in the embedded code snippet below:**

```css
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: no-display;
}

#headermenu {
  display: none;
}

#amenu:hover #headermenu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul id="Header">
    <li>
      <a id="amenu">aaaa
        <div id="headermenu">
          <ul>
            <li><a>menue yek</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**Rendered Output:**

*Visible in DOM*

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul id="Header">
    <li>
      <a id="amenu">aaaa
        </a><div id="headermenu"><a id="amenu">
          </a><ul><a id="amenu">
            </a><li><a id="amenu"></a><a>menue yek</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

You may notice that `#headermenu` is *no longer a child* of `#amenu`, so the following selectors `#amenu:hover #headermenu` fail as a result.

#### The Solution:

To rectify the above processing and formatting issues, consider making the dropdown element a *sibling* to the anchor link - and **not** *nested within* it. Then move your `id` selector to the containing list item itself (parent `li`), e.g:

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul id="Header">
    <li id="amenu"> <!-- add id attribute to containing element -->
      <a>aaaa</a> <!-- close your anchor tag -->
      <!-- make the dropdown a sibling of the anchor tag  -->
      <div id="headermenu">
        <ul>
          <li><a>menue yek</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: no-display;
}

#headermenu {
  display: none;
}

#amenu:hover #headermenu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul id="Header">
    <li id="amenu"> <!-- add id attribute to containing element -->
      <a>aaaa</a> <!-- close your anchor tag -->
      <!-- make the dropdown a sibling of the anchor tag  -->
      <div id="headermenu">
        <ul>
          <li><a>menue yek</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**Alternatively:**

You could keep the `id` attribute on the nested anchor tag and use the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) (`+`) instead.

```css
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: no-display;
}

#headermenu {
  display: none;
}

/* use the adjacent sibling combinator (+) */
#amenu:hover + #headermenu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul id="Header">
    <li>
      <a id="amenu">aaaa</a> <!-- close your anchor tag -->
      <!-- make the dropdown a sibling of the anchor tag  -->
      <div id="headermenu">
        <ul>
          <li><a>menue yek</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

[More on CSS combinators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#Combinators)

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the submenu from the a tag, and put the "amenu" id on the li item, like so:

```css
.navbar{
   width:100%;
   height:30px;
   overflow: no-display;
}
#headermenu{
   display:none;
}

#amenu:hover #headermenu{
   display:block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul id="Header">
    <li id="amenu">
      <a>aaaa</a>
      <div id="headermenu">
        <ul>
          <li><a>menue yek</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: You were trying to put the submenu in the main <a> tag, that does not work because if you click or hover anything inside the <a> tag then you click or hover the <a> tag, not what is inside it.

It now works because now you are using the <li> as a container for both the <a> tag and the submenu, and now you can click and hover the <a> tag separately from the submenu.

Comment: To be honest I cannot really explain exactly why it wasn't working, all I know is that the <a> tag behaves differently from a <li> tag, and trying to display a submenu from inside an <a> tag just doesn't work, I don't exactly know why.

Comment: Also, even if putting "headermenu" inside an <a> tag would display on hover, you would still not be able to click the links inside the "headermenu", as all you would really be clicking is the main <a> tag.